# I already took the census. Why does the 'Census' badge not show on my profile?

Tags: support, bug, badges, login, stack-overflow-developer-survey

I completed [the developer survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417991/take-the-2022-developer-survey), but I did not get the [Census badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/188733#188733) credited to my account. I took the census while I was not logged in and logged in after the fact. I'm not able to retake the census since visiting it shows me the following message: "You have either already completed the survey or your session has expired."

How do I link the survey to my account so I can receive the badge?

Comment: To close voters: even though the Developer Survey is part of SO, at the end, one's given the option to credit the badge to any technical site on the network, so I'm not voting this as only applicable to one specific site. If the team prefers that such questions be asked on MSO, they can migrate it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the Census badge [has been permanently retired and retroactively revoked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424491/removal-of-the-census-badge) from all users on all sites.

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible to "link" your survey to your account - results are completely anonymous and never connected to a specific account.

If for some reason you weren't offered the Census badge, you'll need to [contact us](/contact) and request it be awarded to your account.

Comment: I did that already. Support told me to post this question here.

Comment: @chelium reminds me of tech support of most companies I've worked with in my country. They keep throwing the customer from one to another, like hot potato. At some point, the potato gives up, and they know it. Luckily in your case it's not a broken computer/phone/etc, just a badge. ;)

Comment: That said, your question here, and the answer, are useful for others with same problem, so it turned out to be good thing.